# Error with the command 'make basics ' while install winexe

Tags: installation, winexe

I want to isntall winexe on Ubuntu 13.1 32bit version.
I did exactly after this guide: [Winexe - aldeid](http://www.aldeid.com/wiki/Winexe)
If I execute the command "make basics bin/winexe" there occurs the following error:

```
Compiling ../librpc/idl/atsvc.idl
/usr/include/stdc-predef.h:0: error: Syntax error near '3'
Failed to parse ../librpc/idl/atsvc.idl at ./../pidl/pidl line 608.
make: *** [idl] Error 1
```

I have absolutely no idea how to fix this.
I would be even satisfied with a solution suggestion to this problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

`make "CPP=gcc -E -ffreestanding" basics bin/winexe` works around this error.

Comment: Works perfect for winexe-1.00 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found "another" way to isntall winexe.
[ubuntu forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1339363)
The Donwload-Links to the static version (just unzip and run winexe) are working at the moment (on some other pages they didn't).

I still don't know why the error above occurs, if anybody knows it, please tell me anyway. I am still interessted.

**VERY IMPORTANT EDIT**: After restart winexe gives put an Internal Error signal 11
So I still need a solution for winexe. Either to isntall the verision from git or to fix this error.

EDIT nummber 2: OK, why am I sking questions if I answer them by myself?
The installation form the quide mentiond in my question qorks fine on Ubuntu 12 LTS and winexe-static-version is also ok if you don't make typing errors as I did.