# winexe error when executing make

Tags: python, jenkins, winexe

I would like to try winexe and used following URL to install it http://www.secpod.com/blog/winexe/ .

When I try make basics bin/winexe

I get the following error:

> defined(@array) is deprecated at
>   /home/nlie/Downloads/winexe-1.00/pidl/lib/Parse/Pidl/ODL.pm line 73.
>     (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?) defined(@array) is
>   deprecated at ./../pidl/pidl line 608.    (Maybe you should just omit
>   the defined()?) Compiling ../librpc/idl/atsvc.idl
>   /usr/include/stdc-predef.h:0: error: Syntax error near '3' Failed to
>   parse ../librpc/idl/atsvc.idl at ./../pidl/pidl line 608. make: ***
>   [idl] Error 1

I think it's probably something with it's dependencies and not a real error in the program. Does anyone know more about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error with the command 'make basics ' while install winexe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22299471/error-with-the-command-make-basics-while-install-winexe)

Answer (score 1):

Seems I had to use

make “CPP=gcc -E -ffreestanding” basics bin/winexe

Comment: Why did this work for you? Where did you find the solution? I'd like to understand better since I am facing a similar error while compiling libwmiclient.

Comment: I have no idea how I came up with it, it's been too long. But it looks right now it is also mentioned on the URL that I used in my original post. In following question I found what the -ffreestanding means https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17692428/what-is-ffreestanding-option-in-gcc

Comment: Thanks! I did a little digging of my own, and found this link: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/porting_to.html, which explains the exact reason: gcc version 4.8 onwards, include certain macros by including the file std-predef.h, but this can break some creative uses of the preprocessor.